# How to delete row in listview with SimpleCursorAdapter using button

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I added a delete button in my ListView row and am trying to find a way to make the delete button work inside of my ListView. I can have my code delete the item from the database, I just need help finding where and how to attach a click event to the row's delete button.

I tried creating a custom cursor adapter, but ran into tons of errors when using my application. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

ListRecipients.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListRecipients extends Activity
{
    ListView list;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    //CursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] from = new String[] { DbHelper.NAME, DbHelper.PHONE, DbHelper.MESSAGE };
        String[] column = new String[] {DbHelper.ID, DbHelper.NAME, DbHelper.PHONE, DbHelper.MESSAGE };
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.text_list_name, R.id.text_list_phoneNum, R.id.text_list_message };

        cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, column, null, null, null, null, null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, toViewIDs, 0);
        //adapter = new CursorAdapter(this, cursor);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.NAME));
            String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.PHONE));
            String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MESSAGE));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name = " + name + "\nPhone = " + phone + "\nMessage = " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomCursorAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserCustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    Cursor cursor;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

        final String itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
        Button btnDeleteRecipient = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_list_delete);

        btnDeleteRecipient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.i("ListRecipient", "Delete clicked");
                //deleteRecordWithId(itemId);
                cursor.requery();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); 
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of CursorAdapter try to use arrayAdapret.n in getView() put button.onclick event.inside onclickevent remove that row item using remove(object);

Answer (score -1):

This Idea is Old,

Try to implement Listview with check box and put only a single delete button wherever you like.

When user select multiple check box then get all checked item and then delete that rows only.

here you can find   [complete example](http://developerandro.blogspot.in/2013/09/listview-with-checkbox-android-example.html) .

Comment: What about if I wanted to add an edit button per row?

Comment: If you want to achieve edit you need to listen long press on item and then open context menu give edit option and then do whatever you want.